# How to tell if a scanner can be used over the network with WIA (or another network protocol)

Tags: networking, network-shares, scanner

I have been searching for an ADF scanner/multifunction device that is visible as a scanning device in "Devices and printers" and/or to Windows's "Scan and fax" (since it's WIA-based) software while connected via network.

A little insight:
I am developing an application which communicates with scanners via WIA API and was asked by the client for looking into possibility of using a shared network scanner - one scanner, multiple clients. The scanning needs to be started from my application running on the computer, so starting it from manufacturer software or from device's control panel and dropping them to a network resource like FTP is not suitable.

I know StackExchange isn't very fond of "advise on a product" questions, but after reading hundreds of manuals, spec sheets and forums I'm already rather confused at what protocols or features I need to look for in the spcifications to find a scanner that works via network with WIA, using driver only- not manufacture-specific software (such as HP Scan).

I would be really grateful for any leads in what I actually need to look for to make it work, or if there is any generic protocol for these kinds of things.

Comment: This might fit on [hardwarerecs.se] but it would be good if you can provide objective details for exactly what you need. WIA *implies* Windows, but do you have specific versions you need to support? Do you have a limit on cost? Does it need to be heavy duty or is it a couple of pages per day? There are also some [quality guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality) that might help get you the answer you need.

Comment: Hence why I said I am slightly lost at this point- from my application side it's WIA v2.0 API, but I am aware not every WIA compatible scanner supports network WIA communication, which is why I asked for tips on which protocols/features to look out for in specifications, or even an example product that does such job.
The client wants to use it as a networked department scanner- probably around few 100s of pages a day, budget would be around 700 USD.
Also thank you for pointing out Hardware Recommendations- wasn't even aware it existed, and multiple printer questions led me here.